# HTML table setting td height wont work

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with Internet Explorer 9 and fixed height of a `td`

I need a `td` with `5px` height but in **IE9** its bigger than `5px`.

In Chrome, Firefox and Safari it works

I tried with a **transparent 1px gif** to insert in the `td`, I set the `font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px` and it still won't work.

My test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>test</title>
<style>
    .space{
        height: 5px;
        width: 5px;
        font-size: 0px;
        line-height: 0px;
        background: none;
    }

    table{
        border-spacing: 0px;
        table-layout: fixed;

    }

    td{
        background-color: red;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 1200px;">
        <tr >
            <td rowspan="5"> test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br><br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br> </td>
            <td rowspan="5" class="space"> </td>
            <td rowspan="5"> test2<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br><br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br> </td>
            <td rowspan="5" class="space"> </td>
            <td> test3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="space"> spacer</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> test 5</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="space"> spacer</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> test 5</td>
        </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I have two images:

**Chrome (working):**

[image: chrome(working)]

**IE9**:

[image: ie9]

Answer (score 1):

You can place a div inside the td with a height of 5px. http://jsfiddle.net/aCrbz/3/

```
<td><div class="foo"></div></td>
```

Comment: thank you i tried this with the space class but it didnt work because background:transparent ...

Comment: ok its still not working when im use vertical-align: top in the td ... the text is only in the first row on top. I'm ignore internet explorer :)

Comment: did you try with background: #FFF; ?